# Strange behavior using HTML 'readonly="readonly"' vs. JavaScript 'element.readOnly = true;'

Tags: asp.net, javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, readonly

### Some background

So I was finishing up some enhancements in a web application that does some automatic interpolation of data.  There are a handful of textboxes that the user fills out, and other textboxes in between them have values automatically calculated.  The textboxes that receive automatically calculated values must be readOnly to prevent user changes, but can't be disabled or they won't get submitted on postback.  Each of these textboxes also has a checkbox next to it so a user can consciously check it to make the field writable and thus allow them to override the interpolated value.

The browser: IE 7 (not sure how this behaves in others)

### The issue

When setting the `readOnly` property of the textboxes with JavaScript, the value in the textbox is submitted with the form: I can see it on the server side (ASP.NET) with `myTextBox.Text` and it's in `Request.Form("myTextBox")`.

If I set `ReadOnly="true"` on my `<asp:TextBox />` element and don't use the JavaScript method, the value in the text box is **NOT** available from `myTextBox.Text` (I assume it never made it into the `ViewState`), but it is getting submitted with the form: `Request.Form("myTextBox")` has a value.

### My question(s)

What the heck is going on? Is this by design?  Is this a browser issue? Did I find a bug?  It's annoying that I have to have some extra JavaScript to initially disable the writability of the textboxes when the page loads in order to make my app work.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample of your .aspx file? I just built a small test (using VS2005, .NET 2.0), and set up
    <asp:TextBox id="txtTest" ReadOnly="True" Text="Foo" />
in the .aspx and I'm still able to read it on form submission via txtTest.Text from the codebehind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. As an ASP.NET security feature, setting it to readonly on the server will keep it readonly regardless of what happens on the client. If you want them to be able override it and actually submit a value then it's not really readonly on the server, only conditionally on the client. You can either do a postback when they check the checkbox to change the readonly attribute on the server, or set only the readonly attribute on the client using this ASP.NET code:

```
MyControl.Attributes.Add("readOnly","readOnly")
```

Comment: Thank you!  That makes sense now; wasn't considering the properties on the ASP.NET server control and how they could affect the results.

Comment: That's what I was trying to say, but didn't say it terribly well. :)

Comment: I took a look at the ViewState for the TextBox, and when you set it to be read-only in the code-behind, there is one less item in the ViewState for that item after a postback (as compared to TextBoxes that aren't read-only after a postback).  The value never makes it there, so the .Text property returns emptiness.

Comment: This is all good guys, biut it won't work if the textbox is part of a Gridview or Detailsview for example with edittemplates, inserttemplates, itemtemplates, etc. So you cannot place the attributes.add() in the page_load as the control has not rendered yet. Any ideas on how to get around that?

Comment: @Fernando68, so use a different event. Something like this should work: `GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
            e.Row.FindControl("yourControl").Attributes.Add("readOnly","readOnly");
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I tweaked my sample and I think I see the problem - and I could be wrong, but I think it's behaving as intended.

When you set a field to be ReadOnly on the codebehind, the `ASP:TextBox` seems to become immutable even by JS. I made a change and the change was reflected in JS and in the form, but the TextBox retained its original text value -- unless I looked in the Request. Form as you did.

I don't think this is a bug. I think it's intentional, to keep something completely locked down - readonly on the server side hanging on does seem like a preferred choice.

May I suggest something using hidden input fields and spans or `ASP:Labels` (which effectively render as spans) to give a display aspect that isn't adjustable by the user?

Alternately, if you have access to a JS library (such as jQuery), you could set a CSS class on your TextBoxes (with `CssClass="readonly"` or something like that in your tag), then use the selection process to tweak the attribute, like so (assuming jQuery, easily written in other languages):

```
$("input.readonly").attr("readonly","readonly");
```

That way, you're not rewriting much of your markup and it's a quick'n'easy JS fix.

Comment: I have a workaround using some simple JS as you have provided, so finding a solution isn't a problem.  I'm just trying to understand why there's a difference between setting readonly="readonly" in the markup and setting readOnly=true on the same element but through the DOM.  I can't use labels because I dynamically change the readonly-ness of the fields when the user checks a checkbox next to them, essentially giving themselves permission to make the edit -- I just don't want them accidentally overwriting values.