# Setting textbox to Enable = false is stopping the value from saving

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have a textbox that I would to disable so users can't enter in any text they want. To choose a driver they must click on the magnify glass image and a list of drivers appears.

[image]

When they select a driver from the list, it populates the driver into the textbox. But when I go to save it, it value comes in as blank so no driver gets saved. The problem is setting the textbox to `Enabled = false`.

```
txtDriverName.Enabled = false;
```

If I remove this line the driver will save. But disabling the textbox saves a blank value. How do I stop users entering text in the textbox but still save the value that gets populated from the list?

Comment: Related or duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316399/disabled-textbox-losses-viewstate But how and when do you assign a value to the `TextBox`? Try to do that on aspx or in `Page_Init`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have a function that populates all the textboxes. This function is called from the `Page_Load` method. But thanks the question you linked worked

Comment: Try to call that method from `Page_Init` instead, interested in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
txtDriverName.ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: no same thing happened. Value goes blank when I try save

Answer (score 0):

Answer is setting the textbox to  `txtDriverName.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");`.

Not sure why this worked and setting it to `Enabled = false` or `txtDriverName.ReadOnly = true;` didn't work. But it saves the value in the textbox now

Comment: Because this ensures that the `ViewState` is used to persist the value. If you set `Enabled=False` on serverside ASP.NET will disable viewstate for this control since a disabled control is not meant to change it's value across postbacks.